# How can I batch compile all Flex and Bison files in a folder?

Tags: compilation, batch-processing, bison, flex-lexer

I want to create a .bat file (on windows) that is similar to make on linux!
The ideia is to compile all the .l files and .y files in the folder and then
use the cl (compiler from VS2012) to batch compile all the generated .c files
into .obj and then a final .exe

Is this possible? how can I create this?
all the files in the folder are from the same project and I wanted the .bat file
to accept a name for the final .exe file.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmake in the Visual Studio command prompt just like you used make in linux. There are differences between Gnu Make on linux and Microsoft Nmake but for the simple usage you describe they would be the same. You could even copy over the same Makefile if you are careful.

A simple batch file is fairly straight forward and there are plenty of introductions to batch files available to read. Just as a bash script on linux, a batch file just contains the commands you would have typed at the command prompt, but stored in a file with the *.bat name. For example:

```
@echo off
flex %1.l
bison %1.y
cl /out:%1.exe %1.tab.c
```

You have to make sure that the flex library is available to visual studio to get it to link, however.